# DOM XML - How to get child node?

Tags: java, xml

I have xml like this:

```
<param>
  <name>some_list</name>
  <value>
    <items>
      <item>
        <value>7</value>
        <type>Long</type>
      </item>
      <item>
        <value>23</value>
        <type>String</type>
      </item>
      <item>
        <value>1.0</value>
        <type>Double</type>
      </item>
      <item>
        <value>true</value>
        <type>Boolean</type>
      </item>
      <item>
        <value>13-01-2014 16:03:50</value>
        <type>Date</type>
      </item>
      <item>
        <value>[7, false]</value>
        <type>String</type>
      </item>
    </items>
  </value>
  <type>Collection</type>
</param>
```

I need to get value of **type** node - child od **param** node (in this case 'Collection'). I am not interested children of **item** nodes, so solution like this:

```
NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName("type").item(0).getChildNodes();
Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
return node.getNodeValue();
```

is wrong (it returns 'Long', not 'Collection'!)

Comment: Long is the value tagged by type on the first element e.g item(0) why do you expect it to be String?

Comment: I expect it to be 'Collection' - one lvl lower than 'param' node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns all *descendant* elements. You just want all immediate *child* elements.

You can use `getChildNodes()` and then filter them if you want. For example:

```
NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = children.item(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_TYPE
        && node.getLocalName().equals("type")) {
        // Use the node, get its value etc
    }
}
```

You might want to look at using XPath or an alternative Java XML API (e.g. [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/)) to make this simpler, too. If you do the above a lot, you probably want to extract it to a helper method to return all the direct children with a particular element name (or just the first one).